# Instant run, targetSdkVersion > 20 and changes to AndroidManifes.xml: full build almost everytime

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, instant-run

My project uses (in the gradle file)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xxx.xxxxx"
    versionCode code
    versionName "1.1.0"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

but the new Android Studio 2.0 IDE, perform a **slow and full build** almost every time, and says that the new *Instant Run* feature is not available if target api is 20 or less.

Where's the problem?

I get a full build also when the IDE says the AndroidManifest.xml has changed:

[image: Message from the Android Studio 2 IDE]

**EDIT:**
The "target sdk version" is the target of the phisical device. So this problem is not related to the targetSdkVersion variable in the gradle file. I'm debugging on a 4.0.1 machine, so the IDE shows the message.

More info [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run).

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior in 2.0 right now. It seems like you may have some code that automatically update your AndroidManifest.xml or a resource that is referenced by it. If you can stop auto updating it in your dev/debug environment (you can create a new product flavor), you should then be able to use Instant Run and greatly speed up your iteration cycle.

See the official [Instant Run documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run).